# Wrong results when property name equals search value

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am using Breeze.js in my project and the following query returns me all the group entities that I have in local cache although only one of them has group==group

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('Groups').using(manager).where('group', '==', 'group').executeLocally();
```

Here my metadata definition:

```
{
  "shortName": "Group",
  "namespace": "CM.Models",
  "baseTypeName": "Entity",
  "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
  "defaultResourceName": "Groups",
  "dataProperties": [
    {
      "name": "groupID",
      "dataType": "String",
      "maxLength": 32,
      "defaultValue": "",
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "maxLength",
          "maxLength": 32
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "group",
      "dataType": "String",
      "maxLength": 32,
      "defaultValue": "",
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "maxLength",
          "maxLength": 32
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "groupMembers",
      "dataType": "String",
      "isScalar": false,
      "defaultValue": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it a bug of Breeze.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, I found the answer after digging into breeze.js code. It turns out that it is possible to escape the evaluation side. Therefore the query becomes:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('Groups').using(manager).where('group', '==', "'group'").executeLocally();
```

"'group'" insetad 'group'